# Enviar un post desde javascript

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una vista Create que tiene su Action result para el POST, pero la quiero llamar desde el javascript.

Quiero pasar el valor de un textbox al controlador para poder manejarlo y devolver nuevamente la vista Create pero ahora con un modelo ya configurado y no nulo. (porque envio el nombre de un cliente al controlador, y si ya existía pero estaba deshabilitado entonces quiero que lo pase a la vista Create con un return View(modelo)

He buscado y hablan de usar Ajax, pero la verdad que los ejemplos que vi no me quedaron muy claros.

Es muy simple lo que quiero, es enviar un textbox a un controlador desde javascript.

¿Cual es la manera mas simple de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @Edu, generalmente lo que se hace en ese caso es recibir el form en el action y verificar si existe. Luego informar al usuario que ya existe y retornar el modelo en el mismo action. Puedes ofrecerle al usuario la posibilidad de habilitarlo nuevamente y actualizar los datos.

Comment: Como "recibir el form en el action" ?

Comment: es que para realizar lo que planteas se usa $.ajax de jquery, pero lo que retornas no es un View() sino que retornas un json como respuesta, tambien puedes usar el @Ajax.BeginForm() de asp.net mvc